# What does it mean when => is inside []?

Tags: scala, types

Recently I've seen book titled "Scala: Applied Machine Learning". I found this:

```
type U = List[Fields => Double]
```

I haven't seen  `=>` inside `[]` in many books. Please explain it for me.

Comment: It's a function kind, well among other things... You might want to understand better those here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-functions-as-variables-values-in-scala-fp .
So `List[Fields => Double]` is a kind of list which contains functions which take `Fields` as argument and output a `Double`.

Comment: It means the same thing it means outside of `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the components of `type U = List[Fields => Double]`:

- `Fields => Double` is a function type
- `List` is a type constructor for a collection type
- `type U` is a type alias

For example, say we have the following functions

```
val foo: Int => String = (x: Int) => "hello " + x
val bar: Int => String = (x: Int) => "goodbye " + x
val zar: Int => String = (x: Int) => "greetings " + x
```

Then we could collect them into a `List` of `Int => String` functions like so

```
List[Int => String](foo, bar, zar)
```

in the same way we can collect integers into a list

```
List[Int](1,3,42)
```

In Scala, we say functions are *first class values*, meaning we can use them just like any other value, that is pass them in and out of other functions, add them to collections, assign them to variables etc.

`type U` is a type alias meaning it gives a different name to a type on the right-hand side. We can use it, for example, to simplify a long type name, so instead of writing out `List[Int => String]` we can just write `U`:

```
def qux(c: U): U = c
```

would be the same as

```
def qux(c: List[Int => String]): List[Int => String] = c
```

`List[T]` is a type constructor meaning when we substitute a concrete type for `T`, such as `Int`, or `String`, or `Int => String` we get the corresponding types `List[Int]`, `List[String]`, and `List[Int => String]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a `List` of functions that take an argument of type `Fields` and return a `Double`.

In Java 8 it would be semantically equivalent to `List<Function<Fields, Double>>`. (Not sure if Scala translates it to that underneath the hood yet).

Comment: "Not sure if Scala translates it that underneath the hood yet" Yes (though it's `scala.Function1` and Scala library's `List`).